# How to disable Ctrl-Space selecting chinese keyboard on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, chinese

I would like to use both chinese keyboard and eclipse ctrl-space for suggestions popup. Since I use chinese very rare, I would like just to disable ctrl-space selecting this language.

I have removed this combination from windows' chinese keyboard setup, but it either returns (if I remove) or just works without setting (if chaged).

Hot to disable ctrl-space totally for keyboard?

Comment: The right answer here is probably not how to turn Ctrl-Space of but ask if there are an alternative keyboard sequence that could be used on chines keyboards that gives the same function in Eclipse.  And there are, I just doesn't remember it now. :(  I used to know it when I had chines students.

Comment: Use Alt-/ in Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've been aware of this Windows bug for *years*. After tons of unsatisfying workarounds and fruitless searching the one or two times a year I attempt to find a solution, **I finally have it!**

## Procedure

1. Go to `Start` > Type in `regedit` and start it
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method/Hot Keys`
3. Select the key named:

   - `00000070` for the `Chinese (Traditional) IME - Ime/NonIme Toggle` hotkey
   - `00000010` for the `Chinese (Simplified) IME - Ime/NonIme Toggle` hotkey
4. In the right sub-window, there are three subkeys.

   - Key Modifiers designate <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>/etc and is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (`02c00000`).
   - Virtual Key designates the finishing key and is set to <kbd>Space</kbd> (`20000000`).
5. Change the first byte in `Key Modifiers` from `02` to `00`
6. Change the first byte in `Virtual Key` from `20` to `FF`
7. Log off and log back on. I don't think it's necessary to restart.
8. Do not change the `Hot keys for input languages` in Control Panel, unless you want to do this all over again.

**Notes: Symptoms**

Each registry key (thing that looks like a folder) is for each specific hotkey setting that you would normally find in `Control Panel > Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages > Change keyboards... > Advanced Key Settings > Hot keys for input languages`. The recurring bug is the hotkey being automatically reset to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> even if changed via the GUI.

This is for Windows 7 64-bit, though from my research, it looks like it may work for XP and Vista as well.

Sources:

[Traditional Chinese Pocket IME Hot Key Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904366.aspx)

[Simplified Chinese MSPY 3.0 IME Hot Key Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904626.aspx)

Comment: Hi, It is known that it is fixed in later windows e.g. Windows 10. but how to re-enable it ? I want Ctrl+space to be working in Windows 10 when the Chinese Lang is added.

Comment: @GokulE I'm on Win10 and still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm about to test this. I'm following this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/how-do-i-disable-the-changing-of-languages-when-i/f01de525-73b2-4c4e-969e-b5aa001c0eb7)

Step 1.
<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→`regedit`→`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method/Hot Keys`
`00000010` is for enable or disable the IME
`00000011` is for toggle between full and half width characters
`00000012` is for switch symbol mode

Step 2:
Go whichever hot key you want to modify, right click on the item and select modify,  here are the rules:
Key Modifiers([ref](https://www.cnblogs.com/walzer/archive/2006/02/05/325603.html)):
`00 C0 00 00`, no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Set this value if you don't need the hot key)
`01 C0 00 00`, left<kbd>Alt</kbd>
`02 C0 00 00`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>
`04 C0 00 00`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
`06 C0 00 00`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
Or combination of the above to make your own.

Virtual Key [code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes):
the actual key combination, ascii code
`20 00 00 00`, for <kbd>Space</kbd>
`21 00 00 00`, for <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
`00 00 00 00`, for no key
`ff 00 00 00`, for NONE (Set this value if you don't need the hot key)

Target IME:
leave it as it is, or change it to `00 00 00 00`, for all languages( I suppose).

[Reference Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904626.aspx)

Comment: Tested. It works.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)